# wifi connection is established but internet is not working

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

I use a wifi and its works fine. But when i use other wifi connection is established but internet is not working. It seems no data is recived in my ubuntu 12.04(LTS). And the same wifi connection is working fine in Windows computer.
Help me with this issue....

Comment: i had the same problem a few weeks ago ... turns out the network admin was reconfiguring the firewall rules at the same time ... my point is: it could be **anything**

Answer (score 0):

Check if you received an IP address.

You can do this by opening a terminal and run

```
ifconfig
```

Look for you WiFi adapter, probably wlan0. There should be a line that looks like

```
inet addr:192.168.178.96  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

If this is the case, try to open the web page of your WiFi access point.

Comment: if that looks good look at your route table and see if your have a default route ... if so see if you can ping that gateway